# Turn off 'Close lid to sleep' when only connected to dock/monitor - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, powershell, thinkpad, docking-station

I want to change the 'Close lid to sleep' setting such that:

1. Whenever my laptop is connected to the dock or monitor, closing lid does nothing
2. When I disconnect it from dock/monitor, closing lid puts laptop to sleep.

I want a solution such that it happens automatically when (dis)connecting the dock/monitor without any manual seting change required.

Is there any way to achieve this?
Or any powershell scripts to detect dock/monitor & then execute a command to change 'Close lid' setting.

Edit: `powercfg /setacvalueindex scheme_current sub_buttons lidaction 0` does the close lid setting, how to trigger this when connected/disconnected to dock?

I have a Windows 10 laptop and a thinkpad dock.

Answer (score 0):

This may not do exactly what you want but it works for me. Instead of deciding if docked or connected to monitor, I check if it is powered, since when I am connected to my monitor, I always have the laptop plugged it.

[image]

The downside is that the laptop won't go to sleep when plugged in. In that case, I use the sleep/power button and then close the lid.

Comment: The problem in this case: is suppose you are plugged in and close the lid, then afterwards plug out it, now the laptop remains powered on